# How to consider two columns values in txt file as key, value and write them into a txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a text file with tab delimiter like this:

`id      name   age   sex   Basis    Salary
2345    john    23    M     Monthly  6000
2345    john    23    M     Yearly   72000
4356    mary    26    F     Perday   225
4356    mary    26    F     Monthly  7000`

Take id as key, I need combine the Basis and Salary column values to be the columns in the resultant file as below.

Note: If Perday or Monthly or yearly does not have any values then we should give it as "' '".

`id     Name    age   sex   PerDay  Monthly Yearly
2345    john    23    M     ' '     6000    72000
4356    mary    26    F     225     7000    ' '`

How do we do this in python way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mypath = '/path/to/file.csv'

with open(mypath) as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()

header, body = lines[0], lines[0:]

records = {}

for record in body:
    id, name, age, sex, basis, salary = record.split('\t')
    cached = records.get(id)

    if cached:
        cached[basis] = salary
        records[id] = cached

    else:
        records[id] = {'id': id, "name": name, "age": age, "sex": sex, basis: salary, **{base: ' ' for base in 
                                                                                         set(['Yearly', 'Monthly', 'Perday'])-{basis}}}
```

Brief explanation:

`mypath` is the path to your `.csv` file

I strip off the header and just grab all of the records as a list of strings. Next we iterate through that list

Split each row by `\t` or tab chars, and unpack into the original structure

Do a lookup on the original `id`. If it has already been processed, we just want to add a `basis` entry with the associated salary. If it hasn't been, we add a record that has everything, and the individual `basis` values are unpacked with either the provided `salary` or `' '` as requested

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot use pandas. Is there any way we can achieve this with python?

Comment: With raw python? Sure, I'll edit my answer, give me a few

Comment: Yes raw python. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to use basic python data structures. It outputs everything into a dictionary, which you should be able to do lookups against with relative ease

Comment: When I am trying to execute it throws me an error saying "    records[id] = {'id': id, "name": name, "age": age, "sex": sex, basis: salary, **{base: ' ' for base in 
                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: could be the newline after `for base in`

Comment: No, I checked it. its throwing an error exactly at "**(base:" FYI

Comment: Basic example, but `mydict = {'a': 1, **{b: ' ' for b in {'Yearly', 'Monthly', 'Perday'}-{base}}}` runs just fine. Looking at what you posted, `**(base...` is incorrect because the `**` syntax unpacks a dictionary, while `(base` implies a tuple

Comment: `mydict = {'a': 1, **(b: ' ' for b in {'Yearly', 'Monthly', 'Perday'}-{base})}`
`  File "<stdin>", line 1`
`    mydict = {'a': 1, **(b: ' ' for b in {'Yearly', 'Monthly', 'Perday'}-{base})}`
                          ^
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. That looks like your error, change your parentheses to braces and you should be golden

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
# read each line in your code
input_file = open('filePath',r)
output_file = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
output_file.write('id     Name    age   sex   PerDay  Monthly Yearly\n')
for line in input_file.readlines()[1:]: # excluding the first line
  m = re.search("(\d+)\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+(\d+)\s+([MmFf])\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+(\d+)",line)
  # >>>m
  # >>><_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 41), match='2345    john    23    M     Monthly  6000'>
  if m:
     # >>>m.groups()
     # >>>('Monthly', '6000')
     # based on the montly and perday, multiply the second value and place in your output file
     # based on m.group(5) - leave others as " "
     # if monthly 
     # if early 
     # if daily 

     output_file.write("write your individual outputs" )
```

Comment: Its data from a table and we cannot multiply and place in output file. We just need to read the data from the file and make changes as per the output shown. How can we do this in python?

Comment: For example: If you see john does not have perday data so it should be 'null ' ''.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work best I think. It assumes that the ID number is unique though.

```
import csv

id_column = 0
melt_column = 4
value_column = 5
in_file = "file.csv"
out_file = "out.csv"

new_headers = ['id','Name','age','sex','PerDay','Monthly','Yearly']
header = None
data = dict()


with open(in_file) as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\t"):
        if header is None:
            header = row
            continue
        else:
            melt_idx = new_headers.index(row[melt_column])
            if row[id_column] not in data:
                data[row[id_column]] = row[id_column:melt_column] + ["", "", ""]
            data[row[id_column]][melt_idx] = row[value_column]

with open(out_file, mode="w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter="\t")
    writer.writerow(new_headers)
    for k, val in data.items():
        writer.writerow(val)
```